# XSLT summarize value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to generate an item that accumulates a total for a given XML input.

The XML input is:

```
<catalog xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
  <item id="1" amount="10" />
  <item id="2" amount="20" />           
</catalog>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
 <body>
 <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
 <table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Amount</th>     
  </tr>

  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/item">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@amount"/></td>   

  <br/>
   Total: 

  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>

</table>
```

And this is my output:

```
<html xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<body>
  <h2></h2>
  <table border="1">
     <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <br/>
 Total: 

  </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <br/>
  Total: 

  </tr>
  </table>
```

The result should be Total = 30

How can I implement a sum function that returns the correct total value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`sum()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-sum) function to total the `@amount` values:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/catalog/item/@amount)"/>
```

Note that you'll want to move your `Total:` label along with the above `xsl:value-of` *outside* of your `xsl:for-each` loop.